# Change input value on click depending on it's current value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make it work like this :

**html:**

```
<input type="radio" id="option_1">
<input value="2" type="number">
```

**jquery:**

```
$('#option_1').click(function(){
    //if input value < 3 or > 5 change value to 3:
        $('input').val('3');
    //if input value = 3, 4 or 5 do nothing
});
```

Comment: Translate your comment into an actual `if ( ... )`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan on click

Answer (score 1):

To do what you require you can use a combination of `Math.min()` and `Math.max()`, like this:

```js
let min = 3, max = 5;

$('#option_1').click(function() {
  $('input').val((i, v) => Math.min(Math.max(v, min), max));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="option_1">
<input value="2" type="number"><br />

<input type="radio" name="foo" id="option_2">
Foo
```

The same logic can also be extended to work as the user types a value in to the field to avoid issues whereby the user types a value outside the allowed bounds *after* the radio button is clicked:

```js
let min = 3, max = 5;
let setFieldExtents = () => $('input').val((i, v) => Math.min(Math.max(v, min), max));

$('#option_1').on('click', setFieldExtents);
$('#num').on('input', setFieldExtents);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="option_1">
<input type="number" value="2" id="num"><br />

<input type="radio" name="foo" id="option_2">
Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple condition could check the value of input , using :

```
($yourInput.val() < 3 || $yourInput.val() > 5) && $yourInput.val('3');
```

```js
$(function() {

  $('#option_1').click(function() {
    var $input = $('input[type="number"]');
    ($input.val() < 3 || $input.val() > 5) && $input.val('3');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


click here => <input type="radio" id="option_1"> 
<br>
<input value="2" type="number">
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply do it in this way. Please check the code below**

```
$('#option_1').click(function(){
    var input_value=$('input[type=number]').val();
   
   if(input_value < 3 || input_value > 5) //if input value < 3 or > 5 change value to 3:
    $('input[type=number]').val('3');      
    //if input value = 3, 4 or 5 do nothing 
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
click me : <input type="radio" id="option_1">
<br/><br/>
<input value="2" type="number">
```

Check working fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/farjana_sultana/knpr2vhz/8/